# Можно ли в Blazor сделать какое-то подобие директив из Angular?

Tags: веб-программирование, .net-core, blazor

В Angular можно описать дерективу, а потом вешать ее на компоненты, как атрибут и что-то делать.

Можно ли чего-нибудь подобное сделать в Blazor?

Скажем, деректива, которую повесив на компонент будет писать в лог при наведении курсора на элемент.